# Is there a way to forward my Yahoo mail to my Gmail account without paying?

Tags: gmail, webmail, yahoo-mail

I looked around a little bit on Yahoo and it looks like if I upgrade, I can forward my email. But I'm a cheapskate and I hate checking different accounts. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**update:** It seems like Yahoo closed the loophole below, but I was able to forward my new @ymail.com email account by using this [link](http://popfwd.mail.yahoo.com/pf/PopFwd?.done=http://in.f951.mail.yahoo.com/ym/Options&rand=1255761663). YMMV: another regular @yahoo.com email did not work... [source](http://picobit.wordpress.com/2009/04/10/yahoo-mail-free-pop-access/)

---

I've been forwarding my free Yahoo email to my Gmail for a long time, now...

Try changing your location setting:

> You can forward Yahoo email without
>   having a Yahoo Plus account for FREE.
>   Just change your location setting to
>   Yahoo! Asia. Then your mail settings
>   will allow you to forward or use POP
>   to synch or forward to GMAIL. [This
>   works like a charm!!! This does not
>   change your time zone]

via [WikiHow](http://www.wikihow.com/Switch-from-Yahoo!-Mail-to-Gmail)

Comment: This still works if you use Phillipines instead of Asia.

Comment: It's free to forward yahoo mail to anywhere now. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66949

Answer (score 9):

Is your email `@yahoo.com` or `@ymail.com`?  For YMail, you can check it with pop3 access, and thus you can have GMail check your YMail account using pop3.

Comment: It's free to forward yahoo mail to anywhere now. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/66949

Answer (score 3):

Fortunately, Yahoo now provides free forwarding as per the following:

1. Mouse over the Settings menu icon| select Settings.
2. Click Accounts in the left pane.
3. Click Edit beside "Yahoo account."
4. Select Forward.
5. Enter the address you want to forward your email to and select:

   - Store and forward - Email is saved to your account and sent to the forwarding address.
   - Forward only - All email is sent directly to the forwarding address.
   - Store and forward and mark as read - Email is saved to your account, marked as "Read," and   sent to the forwarding address.
6. Click Save.

Ref. https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN22028.html?impressions=true

Answer (score 0):

Another option for getting a Yahoo premium account is if you are an AT&T customer, you can get it for free. Just follow the [first few steps](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/06/iphone-tip-use-disposable-email.html) on my blog if you need help setting this up.